# Android Intent (ActionNotFoundException)

Tags: android, android-intent

i got the following problem:
I am developing an app which requires the zxing-QR-Code reader to work properly. But how shall I know if it is installed?
I found some code which should fix the problem but wont work, so i figured I might ask wehere I found this code:

```
/**someQC**/
public void function() {
    if(!isIntentAvailable(this, "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN")) {
                    intentNotAvaiable("com.google.zxing.client.android"); //handle no intent
}
/**somemoreQC to deal with the intent**/


private void intentNotAvaiable(String intentName) {
        setContentView(R.layout.intentnotavailable);
        TextView t = new TextView(this);
        t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.aint_available);
        t.setText(intentName + "unbekannt, weiterleitung\n zum AndroidApp Market Place?");

        gotoMarketPlace = ("market://search?q=pub:" + intentName);
    }

public void goToMarketPlace(View view) { //this is the Button handler
        Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH).setPackage("com.android.vending").putExtra("query", gotoMarketPlace);
        startActivity(promptInstall); 
    }
```

So the actual problem is, that when i try to start the marketplace (via a yes button) the app just crashes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`IntentIntegrator` class supplied by ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) to kick off your scans, and it will detect the missing Barcode Scanner application and will lead the user to download it. Or, examine the source code to `IntentIntegrator` and apply its techniques.

Comment: I now try to adapt to the IntentIntegrator, I just don't want to c&p, but I am totally confused by this:                       `public static final Method PACKAGE_SETTER;
  static {
    Method temp;
    try {
      temp = Intent.class.getMethod("setPackage", new Class[] {String.class});
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
      temp = null;
    }
    PACKAGE_SETTER = temp;
  }`

Comment: @Sim: `setPackage()` was added in Android 2.1 or so. They want to use that method if it is available, but if they directly referred to it, their code would crash on older Android devices. Reflection is one way to use newer Android capabilities while maintaining backwards compatibility.

Comment: I now successfully adapted, but even though i installed the Barcode scanner I still get the ActivityNotFoundException for `Intent inte = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN").addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT).putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS","QR_CODE_MODE"); activity.startActivityForResult(inte,42);`

Comment: Srry, my bad i removed the static and forgot to now use the member methode setPackage() of the Intent instead of the static one. Still thx for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To look if the Scanner App is available, search it over the PacketManager.

```
PacketManager pm = this.getPacketManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
return list.size() > 0;
```

The Intent in this example is:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
```

To start the market if the App isn't available i would go it this way over the URI for the App. As i know Uri's with "market://***"-prefix will always redirect in the marketapp.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android"));
startActivity(i);
```

Hop this helps.